# why the ja3 hash changed everytime refresh the webpage

Tags: hash

I am reading some articles that told the ja3 hash will help to recognize the browser fingerprints, when I i access the https://tls.browserleaks.com/json with the google chrome browser. the ja3 hash value always changed. why the ja3 hash changed without change the browser? Am I missing something? I think the ja3 hash will keep the same with the same browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome has started with Chrome 110 (02/2023) to randomize the order of extension in the ClientHello in order to *"reduce potential ecosystem brittleness"*, i.e. TLS implementations making assumptions about the order of extensions they get even though the standard allows (almost) arbitrary order. For more see [Feature: TLS ClientHello extension permutation](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5124606246518784) and [the similar issue with Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1789436).

This has the side effect of getting a different JA3 with each handshake, since JA3 includes not only which TLS extensions are used but also the order in the ClientHello. See also [JA3 uniqueness in modern version of Chrome (which randomizes ClientHello messages) #88](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3/issues/88). There are attempts to get stable fingerprints again by [Normalized Fingerprints](https://tlsfingerprint.io/norm_fp) which don't use the original order of extensions but the sorted order. That's the `ja3n`  visible in [tls.browserleaks.com](https://tls.browserleaks.com/json).